# Can not detect packages in a custom jar added

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, dependencies

I created a Spring boot application - **intake**. I created one another spring boot application as - **integration**. I wanted to add the **intake** as a dependency to **integration** application.

I followed the link - https://happilyblogging.wordpress.com/2017/07/31/using-spring-boot-application-as-dependency-in-another-spring-boot-application-project/ and created the **intake** jar file. Then I added the **intake** jar to maven repository using the command `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=intake-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -DgroupId=oca.integration -DartifactId=intake -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar`

And added the following command to the **integration** app's pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>oca.integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>intake</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

As expected the jar - **intake-1.0.jar** is added as Maven dependency to the **integration** application. But the Application.java in **integration** application can not detect/import the pakage inside the **intake-1.0.jar**. Could someone help me with this ?

Comment: Did try maven clean before doing maven install?

Comment: A spring boot application jar can't be used as a dependencies cause the structure inside the jar file is different than a usual jar file. If you like to consume parts of your spring boot application in other application you need to refactor out that code and make a separate module which than can be consumed by others as a dependency....

Comment: @Clovrr - yeah I did Maven install

Comment: @khmarbaise - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yVzi3wuTUE4 - this video helped us